# White spaces at end of timestamp while using Laravel format functions

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, timestamp

I have a problem while using laravel functions for timestamp formatting, specifically while trying to get 'Month' of timestamps columns. For example:

this is the code of the migration:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();        
});
```

And this is an example of retrieving some of this data

```
    $first  =   factory(Post::class)->create();

    $second =   factory(Post::class)->create([

            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth()
        ]);
```

The result is something like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "year" => "2018"
    "month" => "April    "
    "published" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "year" => "2018"
    "month" => "March    "
    "published" => 1
  ]
]
```

Note there the whitespace after the month.
How should I deal with this?

I'm using postgres 10.3, Laravel 5.

I know I could trim my way up, but that could make the code insanely dirty. I would like to find a solution that makes this work 'as expected to'.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using trim().

Comment: How is the result created?

Comment: If you can't find out why this is happening, you can avoid the messiness by using an eloquent setter. This allows you to only put the trim() method in the setter and everything else will work as expected.